# Matrix Rotation

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, sparse-arrays

If I have a matrix of any size, say

$\begin{pmatrix}
 72 & 32 & 64 \\
 18 & 8 & 16 \\
 63 & 28 & 56 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix}
 72 & 32 \\
 18 & 8 \\
 63 & 28 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

How can I rotate/transform it exactly 45 Degrees (diagonal becomes row) to look like below matrix (preferably sparse array) (not as image) ? Prefer a generic solution

Imagine looking towards 63 in the above matrix diagonally from 64 and fill the space between numbers with zero

[image: diagram for rotating a matrix]
[image: another diagram]

$\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 64 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 32 & 0 & 16 & 0 \\
 72 & 0 & 8 & 0 & 56 \\
 0 & 18 & 0 & 28 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 63 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 32 & 0 & 0 \\
 72 & 0 & 8 & 0 \\
 0 & 18 & 0 & 28 \\
 0 & 0 & 63 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

**Background**

```
below function f generates outer product of digits
f = Outer[Times, ##] & @@ IntegerDigits /@ # &
f[{123, 456}]


4   5   6
8   10  12
12  15  18
```

When this Matrix is rotated 45 degrees

```
rotate45@f[{123, 456}]

0   0   6   0   0
0   5   0   12  0
4   0   10  0   18
0   8   0   15  0
0   0   12  0   0
```

Total of rotated matrix results in

```
Total@rotate45@f[{123, 456}]

4  13       28      27      18
```

Adding above list in following way result is 123 * 456 .

```
04
 13
  28
   27
    18
 56088
```

I am trying to create a demonstration to depict this in an interesting way *will share the details when done*. 
See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_multiplication) for further details

Comment: Great question. :-)

Comment: Out of general interest, why do you want to know?

Comment: @Lucas please see updated details

Comment: @PrashantBhate Aha, thanks.

Comment: @Prashant I notice you never Accepted an answer to this.  Do you find all of them lacking?  Is there something we can do to improve them?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard sorry I was away. done :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
array0 = {{72, 32, 64}, {18, 8, 16}, {63, 28, 56}}; 
array1 = SparseArray[Band[{# - 1 + Length@array0[[#]], #}, Automatic, {-1, 1}] -> 
 array0[[#]] & /@ {1, 2, 3}, {5, 5}]; 
array1 // MatrixForm
```

[image]

**Update:** Generalizing for arbitrary matrix input:

```
rttF = Function[{mat}, With[{dims = Dimensions[mat]},
 SparseArray[Band[{# - 1 + Last@dims, #}, Automatic, {-1, 1}] -> mat[[#]] & /@ 
 Range[First@dims], {Total@dims - 1, Total@dims - 1}]]]
```

Examples:

```
 rttF@array0 // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
mtrx = Partition[CharacterRange["a", "x"], 4];
mtrx // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
Row[MatrixForm@rttF[mtrx[[;; #, All]]] & /@ {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}]
```

[image]

```
Row[MatrixForm@rttF[mtrx[[All, ;; #]]] & /@ {2, 3, 4}]
```

[image]

**Update 2:** shorter version:

```
rttF2 = Function[{mat}, With[{m = Last@Dimensions[mat]},
   SparseArray[Band[{m + 1 - #, #}] -> Transpose[mat][[#]] & /@ Range[m]]]]
```

Answer (score 9):

```
mat = {{72, 32, 64}, {18, 8, 16}, {63, 28, 56}};
With[{j = Length[mat] - 1}, 
     Table[ArrayPad[Riffle[Diagonal[mat, k], 0], Abs[k]], {k, j, -j, -1}]]
```

Answer (score 7):

For any number of dimensions ( two versions):

```
rot[m_] := Transpose@SparseArray[ Flatten@Map[Band[#] -> Transpose[m][[#[[1]]]] &, 
                                Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[Length@m + 1, {2}], {2}]]
```

or (keeping it short)

```
rot[m_]:= With[{t = Transpose}, 
               t[SparseArray[Band@#-> t[m][[#[[1]]]]&/@ t@{#, Reverse@#}&@Range@Length@m]]]


s = {{72, 32, 64}, {18, 8, 16}, {63, 28, 56}}
MatrixForm@rot[s]
```

[image: kguler already uploaded i]

Answer (score 6):

This works with matrix of any size (remove Reverse to get it in other direction)

```
rotate45[m_] := 
 SparseArray@
  MapIndexed[
   Band[{#2[[1]], Length@m + #2[[1]] - 1}, Automatic, {1, -1}] -> 
    Reverse@# & , m]


MatrixForm[rotate45[{{72, 32, 64}, {18, 8, 16}, {63, 28, 56}}]]

0   0   64  0   0
0   32  0   16  0
72  0   8   0   56
0   18  0   28  0
0   0   63  0   0
```

Comment: Slightly shorter, and theoretically one less operation: `Band[{0, Length@m - 1} + #2[[1]], Automatic, {1, -1}] &`

Answer (score 4):

Shorter form of kguler's general function:

```
f[a_?MatrixQ] := Dimensions[a] /. {y_, x_} :>
 SparseArray[Band[{# - 1 + x, #}, Automatic, {-1,1}] -> a[[#]] & ~Array~ y, x + y - {1,1}]

{{72, 32, 64}, {18, 8, 16}, {63, 28, 56}} // f // MatrixForm
```

[image]

J. M.'s code in my own style (just because I feel like it):

```
Table[#2 ~Diagonal~ k ~Riffle~ 0 ~ArrayPad~ Abs[k], {k, #, -#, -1}] &[Length@# - 1, #] &;

{{72, 32, 64}, {18, 8, 16}, {63, 28, 56}} // % // MatrixForm
```

Answer (score 2):

An old-fashioned I guess rotation of indices.

```
Turn[m_?MatrixQ] :=
 With[{ax = {1, Length[First@m]}},
    MapIndexed[Round[Composition[
          ScalingTransform[Sqrt[2] {1, 1}, ax],
          RotationTransform[Pi/4., ax]]@#2] -> #1 &,
     m, {2}]] // Flatten // SparseArray

{{72, 32, 64}, {18, 8, 16}, {63, 28, 56}} // Turn // Normal

(* {{0,0,64,0,0},{0,32,0,16,0},
{72,0,8,0,56},{0,18,0,28,0},{0,0,63,0,0}} *)

Partition[CharacterRange["a", "l"], 3] // Turn // Normal

(* {{0,0,"c",0,0,0},{0,"b",0,"f",0,0},{"a",0,"e",0,"i",0},
{0,"d",0,"h",0,"l"},{0,0,"g",0,"k",0},{0,0,0,"j",0,0}} *)
```