# A rotation-like transform on a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

*Do not be confused with comments, those are for previous version of the question* - Kuba

Imagine I have a matrix of the form:

```
MatrixForm[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16}}]
```

I would like to apply a transform that generates a matrix of the form:

```
MatrixForm[{{4, 8, 12, 16}, {3, 7, 11, 15}, {2, 6, 10, 14}, {1, 5, 9, 13}}]
```

What would be the appropriate terminology for this transformation?  It looks a bit like a 90 degree counterclockwise rotation of the elements in the matrix.

Is there a simple way to do it in *Mathematica* with large matrices?

Comment: What do you mean by "rotate this matrix by 90 degrees"?

Comment: I can't relate the example to a $90^{\circ}$ rotation in any way. By some definition of "rotation," you could apply twice the transformation in [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22836/245).

Comment: @Jens I mean rotation in the sense that we write out the Matrix form of the expression of a surface, and rotated that surface by 90 degrees.

Comment: @sebhofer If you're thinking about a matrix of pixel values, the rotation I describe could be understood and rotating around a point at the center of the matrix.

Comment: 1) see sebhofer's comment 2) even with your interpretation it would be rather 180 not 90 degrees, but still no close since the matrix would be upside-down. 3) do not get me wrong, we want to help you but you have to know what do you want. For example `Reverse@TestMatrix` will do the job but is not a general solution

Comment: @Kuba I absolutely get that everyone is trying to help me here, and it's very much appreciated.  Let me provide a more specific example and cut out inappropriate terminology.

Comment: I deleted my comment because I thought I didn't understand what you want, but now I think it was actually valid. What you want can't be done by `RotationTransform`. Still, I don't understand why this is supposed to be a 90 degree rotation. As @Kuba points out it's a 180 degree rotation + a reflection

Comment: @sebhofer I just provided a hopefully much clearer example of what I'm looking for?

Comment: Strongly related: [(2546)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2546/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
t = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16}}
Transpose@(Reverse /@ t) // MatrixForm
```

It is not just *ad hoc* method. `Reverse/@` is "reflection" in *x* direction (while `Reverse@` in *y*), `Transpose` is "reflection" through *y= -x*. So this composition is not a guess.

Using this remarks it is easily to show some kind reverse approach:

```
Reverse@(Transpose@ t)
```

I used "reflection" because is not a real reflection, only positions are reflected. In our case coordinates origin is at the center of `MatrixForm`. I haven't said `Matrix` intentionally to not be confused what is center of the matrix for even dimension case.

One could show good mathematical notation in this case. I'm not experienced in dealing with groups so I will not do this ;)

Comment: Thanks - for some reason, this transformation is happening with halirutan's answer to my question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28746/selecting-morphological-components-of-a-certain-size-centered-on-points-of-int